# cv.CalibrateCamera2 (python) "Both matrices must have the same number of points"

Tags: python, linux, opencv

A fairly simple question I hope; I am trying to use the following openCV command;

```
cv.CalibrateCamera2(object_points2, image_points2, point_counts2, cv.GetSize(image), intrinsic_matrix, distortion_coeffs, rvecs, tvecs, 0)
```

But I recieve the following error;

```
cv.error: Both matrices must have the same number of points
```

Using numpy.shape and numpy.array, the shape of the arrays are;

```
print shape(array(object_points2)) --> (980, 3)
print shape(array(image_points2)) --> (980, 2)
print shape(array(point_counts2)) --> (20, 1)
print shape(array(intrinsic_matrix)) --> (3, 3)
print shape(array(distortion_coeffs)) --> (5, 1)
print shape(array(rvecs)) --> (20, 3)
print shape(array(tvecs)) --> (20, 3)
```

I am clearly missing something but have been trying to figure this out all day!
Am I being stupid?

Many thanks in advance! :)
Josh

Comment: are you using CvMat for your matrices?

Answer (score -1):

You've probably solved it, but for future reference:
I had such error when data in point_counts2 did not face the length of object_points2.